# Coldfusion opencsv csvWriter - I get writeNext method was not found

Tags: coldfusion, opencsv

I have the following code:

```
<cfset csvFilename = 'myCSV.csv'>
<cfset fileWriter = createobject("java","java.io.FileWriter").init("#csvFileName#")>
<cfset csvWriter = createObject("java","com.opencsv.CSVWriter").init(fileWriter, ",")>

<cfset csvWriter.writeNext('{"1","2"}', true)>
<cfset csvWriter.flush()>
<cfset fileWriter.close()>
<cfset csvWriter.close()>
```

When I run the page I get this error message:

> The writeNext method was not found.
>
> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and
>   argument types or the writeNext method is overloaded with argument
>   types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0
>   methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object
>   and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to
>   reduce ambiguity.

I have searched the internet and cannot seem to find any examples of using csvWriter with Coldfusion and I am not sure why it is not working.  I have a working example of csvReader and ReadNext, but not WriteNext.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?  I have tried to do a javacast but that didn't work either.

```
<cfset csvWriter.writeNext(javacast("string",'1,2'))>
```

I am using Coldfusion 11 with opencsv-3.8.jar

Comment: Nice first question 1+. Welcome to S.O. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the API, that overload of [writeNext()](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) expects a `String[]`, or an array of Strings. CF arrays are a little different than Java's, but they are [compatible](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7884.html). Either of these would work:

```
<cfset csvWriter.writeNext( ["1","2"], true)>
<cfset csvWriter.writeNext( javacast("String[]", ["3","4"]), javacast("boolean", true))>
```

As an aside, skip the call to `fileWriter.close()`. When you call `CSVWriter.close()`, it closes the underlying writer for you. Calling both will cause an error.

> `<cfset csvFilename = 'myCSV.csv'>`

Without a full path, I am not sure where that file will end up. Always specifying a full path can save a lot of head scratching later on ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I think it may have been a combination of me not having the full path to the file, because I tried all sorts of combinations for the array and string, but with no luck.  With a full path it is working.  I appreciate your time in answering and confirming that it would work.

Comment: Heh, it happens. One particularly fun round of "oh file where art thou?" convinced me to embrace full paths ;-) Anyway, glad it is working!